# Critical angle in General Relativity

Tags: general-relativity, optics

Analogies between optical propagation in different refractive media and the effect of gravity in light geodesics are well established. But in optics one can have total internal reflection if certain condition between the angle of the ray and the isosurface of refractive index is below a value. I've never read about the existence of an equivalent phenomena happening in General Relativity

> **Question:** Is the existence of critical angles of reflection in geodesic propagation in GR forbidden by the Raychaudhuri equation?

Comment: Why Raychaudhuri equation specifically? For that matter how do you perceive 'non-total reflection' would work in GR on the level of geodesics? I could imagine 'reflection-refraction' pattern for wave equation in curved background but not for the geodesics.